# How to complete I-9 form?

Tags: usa, visa, canadian-citizens, employment

I'm going to US to get TN visa and employer sent me email to complete [I-9 form](http://www.newi9.com/):

> ***Please complete the following process for filling in the I-9 form prior to Day 1 as you will not have access to complete this process at
>   the office.

I'm trying, but it's required to enter my US address, which I don't have yet. When I try to use Canadian address, I get the following errors:

[image]

I can't call to employer, because it's weekend now and I'm going to cross border tomorrow.

Can I complete this form later or it's required before getting TN?

In [this instruction](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/Resources/E3en.pdf) it's written:

> Each newly hired employee should complete and sign Section 1 no later
>   than the first day of employment, regardless of his or her immigration
>   status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the instructions to the Form](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf):

> Form I-9 is used for verifying the identity and employment authorization of individuals hired for employment in the United States. All U.S. employers must ensure proper completion of Form I-9 for each individual they hire for employment in the United States. This includes citizens and noncitizens. Both employees and employers (or authorized representatives of the employer) must complete the form. On the form, an employee must attest to his or her employment authorization. The employee must also present his or her employer with acceptable documents evidencing identity and employment authorization. The employer must examine the employment eligibility and identity document(s) an employee presents to determine whether the document(s) reasonably appear to be genuine and to relate to the employee and record the document information on the Form I-9. The list of acceptable documents can be found on the last page of the form. Employers must retain Form I-9 for a designated period and make it available for inspection by authorized government officers. NOTE: State agencies may use Form I-9. Also, some agricultural recruiters and referrers for a fee may be required to use Form I-9.

There is no requirement for an I-9 to be completed for obtaining a TN visa but your employer must have one on file for you.

And the only time you're able to use a Canadian address is if you're a "border commuter" or living in Canada but working in the US.  So i would suggest getting a place to live and then filling out the form.  I don't think you intend to live on the streets.

Comment: As I added in question you need to complete this form before you start to work. But I need to go to US to find place, it can take several days. How I can enter Canadian address? I don't see "border commuter" option there.

Comment: @Alex You will need to print the form and fill out by hand.  And you're not a border commuter so it would be illegal. And why such a rush?  Are you starting work on Monday?

Comment: yes, starting Monday, going to go to US tomorrow.

Comment: they sent me link to I-9 form: http://www.newi9.com/

Comment: Then go to the US come to the employer and ask them about the form.  Since it's for them.

Comment: yes, I will, but they said it should be completed prior to Day 1 and Day 1 is Monday.

Comment: @Alex It's been a common practice that on your first day you finish HR paperwork.  So your day will start at 11am rather than 9

Answer (score 1):

Completing I-9 form:

1. In dropdown States you can choose Canada option and then you can use your Canadian address.
2. When you get TN, you get I-94 Number, which is required for completing form.

It's enough for completing Section 1.